# LibreOffice Calc: What is the data range syntax?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I want to specify a graph's data ranges, but I don't know what format the data range specifier strings are in. Specifically, I'd like to specify all cells in Column A starting and including row 2 for a graph.

I tried checking the [LibreOffice wiki](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/HowTo/Calc/Defining_a_Data_Range) which unhelpfully links to the [OpenOffice wiki](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Defining_a_Data_Range) which isn't helpful either.

Comment: LO Calc accepts an entire column in the form A:A, but it doesn't accept that form with a starting row.  If you need to specify a starting row, you also need to specify an ending row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's in row 1?  If it's the column label, then `Sheet1.A:A` works.  Apparently, Calc ignores rows that do not contain numeric values.

[image: $Sheet1.$A:$A]

Otherwise, use `Sheet1.A2:A1048576` for the [maximum number of rows](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Faq/Calc/022).

Either way, however, it's much slower than specifying only the rows that contain data, for example `Sheet1.A2:A100`.

**EDIT**:

There are workarounds for automatically expanding the chart's area.  Browse through these related questions:

- https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/16502/how-do-i-insert-named-ranges-in-charts/
- https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=87069
- https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/124256/dynamic-range-for-chart/
- https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=59742

Comment: Can I specify the EXACT number of rows with some kind of sheet variable instead of a literal number?

Comment: It seems not.  I defined a named range with *Sheet -> Named Ranges and Expressions -> Define*, but the chart did not accept the name.  See links in edited answer.